# Подпрыгивание списка

Tags: html, jquery, css

Написал тестовый dropdown. При нажатии на "Все категории" нормально открывается список. Но если в Google Chrome уменьшить масштаб до **67%**, то можно заметить подпрыгивание списка при открытии.

С чем это связано и как можно это исправить? Возможно я не так что-то рассчитываю в скрипте.

```js
categories = {
 openDropdownList: function(obj, id) {
  var padding = $('#'+id).find('.title').css('padding-top').match(/\d+/);

  $('#'+id).toggle().css({
   left: $(obj).position().left - padding,
   top: $(obj).position().top - padding,
  });

  $('#'+id).find('.title').html($(obj).text());
 }
}
```

```css
*, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {overflow-x: hidden; background: #ededed; color: #333333; font-size: 18px; font-family: tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif, Lucida Sans; font-weight: normal; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; zoom: 1;}

a {text-decoration: none; border: 0px; outline: none; cursor: pointer; color: #1e7ec8;}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
a.dotted {text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted #4d76a3; padding-bottom: 2px;}
a.dotted:hover {text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #4d76a3;}

.none {display: none}

#categories_dropdown_list {position: absolute; width: 200px; background: #ffffff;}
#categories_dropdown_list .list a {display: block; padding: 8px;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="padding: 50px"></div>
  
  Категория: <a href="javascript://" onclick="categories.openDropdownList(this, 'categories_dropdown_list'); return false">Все категории</a>

  <div id="categories_dropdown_list" class="none br2px">
    <div class="list">
      <a href="#" class="title" onclick="categories.openDropdownList(this, 'categories_dropdown_list'); return false"></a>
      <a href="#">Категория 1</a>
      <a href="#">Категория 2</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5es1bm9c/5/

Comment: Мне кажется, что это из-за пиксельной модели происходит. Размеры получаются не целые. Я бы на таком не заморачивался

Comment: @Сергей, я бы тоже не заморачивался, но на сайте, который я делаю, такая беда при 90%. Хочется избавиться от этого :(

Comment: использование em в отступах может решить локально проблему. В таком случае на одном масштабе прыжки исчезают, на другом появляются. Мне кажется, что это не решаемо

Answer (score 1):

Вроде работает, если padding в блоке обнулить, а использовать line-height для всех элементов списка, кроме первого

```
#categories_dropdown_list .list a:not(:first-child) {display: block; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;}
```

Comment: Ну это впринципе тоже самое, что убрать у ссылок padding, тогда будет всё нормально. Но так не годится. Мне кажется, что я неправильно что-то рассчитал в коде, поэтому так и криво работает.

Comment: Но в этом случае padding между элементами списка же сохраняется, что и требуется. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: но нужен padding у ссылок со всех сторон, как в примере. А тут его вообще нет, только межстрочный отступ.

Comment: @ModaL никогда не масштабируй на колесико, там почти всегда не корректно отображает элементы. Используй инструменты веб разработки типа "Device mode" в chrome

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, но ведь пользователь может изменить масштаб и там кривизна эта.

Comment: @ModaL ну, маловероятно что кто то будет уменьшать масштаб, пользователь уже заходит с определенным разрешением экрана, ты под это должен затачивать приложение. А то что у тебя прыгает на 1px при масштабе, это ерунда. А вот если прыгает при 100% размерах но на меньших разрешениях это уже плохо. Не нужно оценивать то, как смотрится дизайн изменяя масштаб. Нужно менять разрешение. На моей практике я ни разу не встречал людей которые изменяли масштаб (Я говорю про юзеров). Т.к. они не знают что так можно делать. Это избыточный функционал

Comment: @ModaL и вопрос организационного характера, почему бы не вложить  выпадающий список в одно место где будет `a`. Тогда не нужно искать положения отступы и т.д. И все будет работать ещё лучше.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, умеешь ты убеждать) Спасибо, теперь не буду мучаться и оставлю как есть)